# Marker positions got updated but the marker did not get redrawn on google map when using geolocator pub dev

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to make a moving google map marker according to the user location, I use the geolocator listen function from the geolocator pub dev. The position of the markers got updated however the marker did not show up on the google map at all I tried using setState(){} to refresh the map, however nothing change.

Here's the function that I use

```
void listenToLocation()
  {
    Position? userposition;
    
    final LocationSettings _locationSettings = LocationSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,distanceFilter: 100);
    userStreamlocation = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: _locationSettings).listen(
    (userposition) {
        print(userposition == null ? 'Unknown' : '${userposition.latitude.toString()}, ${userposition.longitude.toString()}');
        useablepos=LatLng(userposition.latitude, userposition.latitude);
        _Navmarkers.remove(UserMarker);
        print('USABLE POSITION:' + useablepos.toString());
        UserMarker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('User'), 
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueCyan),
            position: useablepos,
            draggable: true,); 
        _Navmarkers.add(UserMarker);
        setState(){};
        print('User Location :' + UserMarker.position.toString());
    });         
  }
```

I am able to remove the user marker and replace it with a new marker that have the new position however the marker did not show up on the googlemap

Here's the image to show that the LatLng keep getting updated,
[image]

Edit: UI Screenshot, there is only a single button that function to start the listen function
[image]

Update: I tried several thing and the only thing I found out is that the listen run outside the map state, I still have no idea what to do

Comment: can  you share Your   Screen UI?

Comment: I have add the Screen UI screenshot, is the code needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this after finding out that the marker didn't got updated because it is in a different state than the main widget, I fix it trough the use of the statebuilder widget. Apparently without statefulbuilder, the setState refresh the whole app but not what the function do. here's the code snip

```
StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setMapState) {
          setMapState(
            () {},
          );

          void _whenMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
            //debugPrint('>>>>>>>>> onMapCreated');
            mapController = controller;
            _Navmarkers.clear();
            _navPolylines.clear();
            var direction =
                await LocationService().getDirectionNoWP(userOrigin, userGoal);
            _setPolylines(direction['polyline_decoded']);
            setMapState(
              () {},
            );
          }

          return Column(children: [
            Expanded(
                child: GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition:
                  CameraPosition(target: _kGooglePlex, zoom: 11),
              markers: _Navmarkers,
              polylines: _navPolylines,
              onMapCreated: _whenMapCreated,
            )),
            Row(
              children: [
                ButtonBar(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Position? userposition;

                          const LocationSettings _locationSettings =
                              LocationSettings(
                            accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
                            distanceFilter: 100,
                          );
                          userStreamlocation = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
                                  locationSettings: _locationSettings)
                              .listen((userposition) {
                            _Navmarkers.clear();
                            _Navmarkers.add(Marker(
                                markerId: MarkerId('User'),
                                position: LatLng(userposition.latitude,
                                    userposition.longitude),
                                icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                                    BitmapDescriptor.hueRose)));
                            setMapState(() {                            
                            });                            
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.navigation)),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setMapState(
                            () {                             
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh)),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          dispose();
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.stop))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ]);
        },
      ),
```